# How to create dictionary that gives location of word in a file

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, indexing

[code of what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFDDA.png)

I need to write a code that would reads a file that is a string and then returns a dictionary with the key being the word and the value being the index of where the word occurs within the file. 
For example, if the string was "I want a cookie and a soda", the dictionary would be

```
`{"I":[0], "want":[1] "a":[2,5], "cookie":[3], "and":[4], "soda":[6]}.`
```

Comment: Hey Henry, welcome to SO have a read of [ask] for now can you post your code here as text and tell us what you've tried along with the error you have? from your code I can see you've tried something but tell us the error. Just a word of advice, SO isn't a free code-writing sevice if your post comes across that way it's bound to get down-voted. Don't be discoureged though, programming is hard and we all need a little help. Good luck!

Comment: For next time - Paste your code as text, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}

with open("TempFile.txt") as f:
    for i, word in enumerate(f.read().split()):
        d[word] = d.get(word, []) + [i]
```

**Outputs**

`{'I': [0], 'want': [1], 'a': [2, 5], 'cookie': [3], 'and': [4], 'soda': [6]}`

Its more efficient to use [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to keep a running index, instead of calling `list.index()` every iteration.

Comment: what do the `[]` indicate for the second argument in `,get` ?

Comment: @Datanovice A default return value. If the key doesn't exist then an empty list will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

content of test.txt: this is a cookie

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read()
    contents = contents.split(" ") #split string into a list

    count = 0

    dict = {}

    for word in contents:
        dict[word] = count
        count += 1
    print(dict)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP desires.